# Unable to convert DataFrame to an HTML table

Tags: python, html, dataframe, variables

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to include both the Name Variable and Dataframe variable in the HTML.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
    Name = "Tom"
    Body = Email_Body_Data_Frame

    html = """\
    <html>
      <head> 
      </head>
      <body>
              Hi {0}
              <br>
          <br>
              TEXt TEXT  TEXT  TEXT  TEXT   
          <br> 
          <br>
              {1}
          <br>
             TEXT  TEXT  TEXT  TEXT  TEXT  TEXT 
      </body>
      
      <br>

    </html>
     """.format((Name,Body).to_html())
```

The error I get is associated with this line of code:

```
.format((Name,Body).to_html())
```

Comment: See [ask]. Create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. If your error is from `.format((Name,Body).to_html())`, your code to send an email is irrelevant. Personal anecdotes make your question longer than needed. You should modify your question.

Comment: Joe, were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataframe variable is a simple string. To use `to_html`, you need to specify a Pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) object. `to_hmtl' will create a html table. Try this:

```
name = 'Tom'

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col 1': ['Text', 'Text'], 
                   'Col 2': ['Text', 'Text'], 
                   'Col 3': ['Text', 'Text']}) 
html_table = df.to_html()

html_bef_table = """
                 <html>
                    <head> 
                    </head>
                    <body>
                       Hi {0}
                       <br>
                 """.format(name)
html_aft_table = """
                       <br>
                    </body>
                 </html>
                 """

html = html_bef_table + html_table + html_aft_table
```

Comment: Thanks i got it sorted with some help.

Comment: The code that was used is as follows:-    """.format(Name,Body.to_html())